# Is a contract valid if it releases a party from liability for probable injury?

Tags: contract-law, liability

Suppose party A contracts with party B to release party B of liability for all possible injury resulting from party B providing party A a service in which there is significant risk of injury. If a strict probability figure is needed for this scenario, consider it >= 50%. This is in California.

Question form 1: This probability figure is included in the contract.
Question form 2: This probability is common knowledge (e.g. jumping out a third story window)

Comment: What exactly is the question about such a contract? Can it be legal?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Good clarification, aided by an answer below : I forgot that in contracts we talk about "enforceability" more than "validity" or "legality".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A release from liability for negligence is generally enforceable.

A release from liability for intentional acts is generally not enforceable.

Note also, that at a sufficiently high percentage risk (e.g. 99%), describing the source of the liability as negligence rather than an intentional act is, as a practical matter, no longer viable with respect to any party who is in any respect the cause of the injuries. Where that threshold lies would have to be determined on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

> Is a contract valid if it releases a party from liability for probable injury?

Yes, assuming that (1) the service or solicitation thereof is not outlawed, and (2) by "*injury resulting from party B*" you mean injury suffered *by* A. The contract in both of forms 1 and 2 is valid, since it meets the essential requirement that the parties *know* the terms/risks/etc. they *willfully* accept.

One important thing to keep in mind is that the parties' awareness of risk does not release party B from the *covenant of good faith and fair dealing* that is prerequisite (and presumed) in contract law. This means that the contract does not entitle party B to take advantage of, or unjustifiably exacerbate, the risk to which party A is subjected. In line with this, see the [*Restatement (Second) of Contracts*](https://www.nylitigationfirm.com/files/restat.pdf) at § 195(1) (stating that a contract is unenforceable if harm is caused *intentionally* or *recklessly*).

If the term "*injury resulting from party B*" reasonably or foreseeably implies a scenario where third parties might get injured, the contract would be *unenforceable on grounds of public policy*. See the *Restatement at § 178*. It might not be suffice that party A guarantees he will take responsibility for injuries caused by party B to others. Third parties are not partaking in the contract, whence it cannot be said that they knowingly and willfully accept the conditions therein.

Comment: The Restatement (Second) of Contracts is available [here](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf), now that the law firm of the link in this answer removed that resource and posted some useless "overview of contract law" instead.